# Protractor E2E angular "angular could not be found on the window"

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a strange error after running my tests in angular project  `Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"`. My Protractor configuration looks like this:

```
require('coffee-script').register();

exports.config = {
  seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
    //'chromeOptions': {
    //  'args': ['--disable-extensions']
    //}
  },

  specs: [
    '*_spec.coffee'
  ],

  allScriptsTimeout: 10000000000,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9003/',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000000000
  }
};
```

And test:

```
loginPage = require './pages/log_in_page'

describe 'Log In', ->

      it 'shows after login', ->
        loginPage()
        .setEmail('test@dispatch.me')
        .setPass('a46s75d4as765d4a6s7d54as76d5as74das76d5')
```

Get info from page:

```
module.exports = ->
      @email = element By.css '.test-i-login'
      @password = element By.css '.test-i-password'

      @setEmail = (name) =>
        @email.sendKeys(name)
        this

      @setPass = (number) =>
        @password.sendKeys(number)
        this
      this
```

There're some similar issues on github, but there I didn't find a solution working for me. Thx for answering.

Comment: Could it be possible that the window you are talking about is Non-Angular? Such an error appears in such a case

Answer (score 14):

Changing `framework` option in Protractor config to `'jasmine2'` fixed this issue for me.

See [this thread](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1978) for further information.

Comment: yes this worked for me to . i got this issue after i update to protractor 2.0 . just add `framework: 'jasmine2',` to the conf.js file

Answer (score 6):

In my scenario, login page is non angular, tried the below way, worked out for me

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys('binnu');
```

Answer (score 5):

Protractor is built to test Angular applications, meaning web pages that have an `ng-app` tag in the body of the HTML and controllers that correspond to Angular code in a Javascript file.

The reason Protractor is so useful is that Angular applications run *asynchronously*, meaning that they're not always finished loading when the web page loads. Most testing frameworks would try to click things, type things, etc. before the page is completely ready. Protractor detects all the Angular processes running in the background so that you don't accidentally do something before everything is ready.

What Protractor is telling you is that it didn't find any Angular processes running on the page. Your page might work fine, but it just doesn't rely on Angular in a way that Protractor can recognize.

That doesn't mean Protractor can't test the page. You can access regular WebDriver commands using `browser.driver.any_webdriver_command_here()`. You'll just be missing out on the fantastic synchronizing capabilities that Protractor offers.

Comment: Nah, it was other thing, than protractor. I had my gulp task run wrong and chromdriver path wrong, so that it couldn't do a thing without chrome operations.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happened, because I had chromedriver path installation wrong. And that's why I got this message “angular could not be found on the window”. The other problem I had is that, I needed to run webdriver manually as background process. This solves by making right gulp task( which I made wrong), that'll look something like this:

```
gulp.task ['test'], ->
   runSequence start_server, run_protractor, end_server.
```

Suppose it'll help somebody, who'll have similar(silly) problems.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where you changed the chromedriver path? An example of your actual gulp task with code would be helpful as well. Thanks.