# Protractor Throws Error on Assigning Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
var itemStatus =  element(by.model('item.statusId')).getText();
```

This causes protractor to throw:

> Uncaught exception: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with
>   the page: "Angular could not be found on the window" Process exited
>   with error code 1.

Can someone explain why? This doesn't throw:

```
var itemStatus = element(by.model('item.statusId'))
```

Is it something to do with promises, it can't execute `.getText()` until the element is located?

I guess I have a weak understanding of the basics here.

Update:

```
var itemStatus = element(by.model('item.statusId'))
// var itemStatus =  element(by.model('item.statusId')).getText(); //was throwing with this
```

And then used below, before the code was commented out, I simply did not run the ".getText()" in the expect.

```
it('Should check item status, verify it is Checked Out.', function(){
    expect(itemStatus.getText()).toBe('Checked Out');
    //expect(itemStatus).toBe('Checked Out'); //this is how it was during error
});
```

and the html:

```
<div class="form-control ng-binding ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" ng-model="item.statusId" disabled="disabled">Checked In</div>
```

I want to note that even with all the expect statements commented out, the script would throw an error when I tried to getText() for var itemStatus.

Sorry, forgot config:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['transfer_spec.js']  
}
```

Comment: `Angular could not be found on the window` usually means protractor could not synchronize with the angular application. Where do you have `ng-app` defined? Are you bootstraping angular manually?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216445/protractor-e2e-angular-angular-could-not-be-found-on-the-window, https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1760.

Comment: Hey alec, sorry, I had to leave after I posted that question. NOTHING changes in the application except removing .getText() - that's what makes it throw or not throw an error. I was wondering if there is something wrong with trying to get a property of an element, but I guess not. Maybe just an error?

Comment: Are you sure nothing changed in the application itself? Have you upgraded protractor or changed the protractor config?

Comment: Yea, I can literally make it throw/not throw by removing/adding .getText() - I tested it about five times (once again just now). To clarify - it's not even a problem, I got around it before making the post. I just wanted to see if it's something known.

Comment: Can you show your protractor config and the HTML representation of the element with "item.statusId" model? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, how have you got around it?

Comment: Thanks for all the additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with where have you defined the `itemStatus` variable. If it's defined out of scope of `describe/it`, you may fall into a synchronization issue between protractor and angular - at the moment `getText()` is called, it's too early, `protractor` has not yet received the Angular "I'm ready" signal. Have you declarations inside the `describe/it`, or inside a Page Object:

```
var MyPage = function () {
    this.status = element(by.model('item.statusId'));
};
module.exports = new MyPage();
```

Usage:

```
var myPage = require("MyPage.js")

describe("My test", function () {
    it("Should check item status, verify it is Checked Out.", function () {
         expect(myPage.status.getText()).toEqual("Checked Out");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot as usual.